# Laptop with no battery at Abu Dhabi airport security check

Tags: airport-security, electronic-items, etihad, abu-dhabi

I have a Lenovo X61T laptop that has no battery, and the power cable is broken and doesn't show the "charging" light on the laptop when I plug it in.

I am traveling from Beirut, Lebanon to Incheon, South Korea via Abu Dhabi (Etihad).

The thing I'm worried about is that I've read some security checks at Abu Dhabi airport require you to turn on your laptop, or it will be confiscated. How am I supposed to turn it on when the power cord is damaged?!

I don't want to risk putting it with my checked luggage, because I don't want it damaged.

Comment: The first two questions appear closely related, but the third is a completely different topic and should be its own question.

Comment: I separated it.

Comment: Unrelated question removed. Feel free to post it as a separate question.

Comment: @JonathanReez I orginally posted 3 questions. Roddy of the Frozen Peas   asked me to separate the 3rd so I did.

Comment: Simply turning it on (you said yourself that the "charging light" doesn't lit, but I guess that the notebook still works while attached to a power plug).

Comment: @Noldor130884 the power plug is broken, that's why. Before it broke, the laptop worked well while plugged in.

Comment: and you have absolutely no battery to show to the security that your notebook works? I don't see any other solution but the following two: either pack your notebook in your suitcase, or pray that you have good luck and they don't ask you to turn the notebook on...

Comment: I don't have a battery. It's a secondhand, and the person who gave it to me didn't give me a battery. Well, he did, but it was not for the model.

Comment: I have sent a laptop in checked baggage several times, with no signs of damage. I just make sure there are at least a couple of inches of clothing between the laptop and the outside of the suitcase, in all directions.

Comment: OK, turns out this question is useless. I was carrying another laptop with me, and they didn't even ask me to take it out of the backpack it was in. Also, the signs said this would be carried out on flights to the US, UK, and Canada.

Answer (score 4):

From @Newton's comment (to whom credit):

> I am an American and I was asked to turn my laptop and tablet on when traveling from Pakistan to Qatar. The tablet was broken (hence couldn't be powered on) so they did some extra checks on it and gave it back to me.

If this example was following standard policy, security should be able to verify your laptop is a laptop without powering it on.

Comment: Had a similar experience in  Istanbul, Moscow, Hong Kong, Shanghai, Guangzhou, Beijing, Singapore, Tel-aviv, New york ( both La Guardia and JFK ) and maybe several others I do not remember now ( my work requires me to travel a lot with dis-functional specialized equipment ).  just takes more time ( allow for it .. ) so summing up - this seems to be the norm.